# Physical packaging type is missing or invalid

Tags: fedex

I am able to receive rates from FedEx API with my PHP library. But its only regular request. When I try to have Freight LTL Rate API request it shows me error one by one. I almost fixed most of them but still having problem with `Physical packaging type is missing or invalid`.

I tried to figure out where is the problem with WSDL file but no luck. There is nothing in there.

If you have any working example for Freight LTL please answer me. Thank you

Here is my code:

```
<?php
// Copyright 2009, FedEx Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Version 12.0.0

require_once('../../fedex-common.php5');

$newline = "<br />";
//The WSDL is not included with the sample code.
//Please include and reference in $path_to_wsdl variable.
$path_to_wsdl = "../wsdl/RateService_v31.wsdl";

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "1");

$client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl, array('trace' => 1)); // Refer to http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.soap.php for more information

$request['WebAuthenticationDetail'] = array(
    'ParentCredential' => array(
        'Key' => getProperty('parentkey'),
        'Password' => getProperty('parentpassword')
    ),
    'UserCredential' => array(
        'Key' => getProperty('key'),
        'Password' => getProperty('password')
    )
);
$request['ClientDetail'] = array(
    'AccountNumber' => getProperty('shipaccount'),
    'MeterNumber' => getProperty('meter')
);
$request['TransactionDetail'] = array('CustomerTransactionId' => ' *** Rate Request using PHP ***');
$request['Version'] = array(
    'ServiceId' => 'crs',
    'Major' => '31',
    'Intermediate' => '0',
    'Minor' => '0'
);
$request['ReturnTransitAndCommit'] = true;
$request['RequestedShipment']['DropoffType'] = 'REGULAR_PICKUP'; // valid values REGULAR_PICKUP, REQUEST_COURIER, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['ShipTimestamp'] = date('c');
$request['RequestedShipment']['ServiceType'] = 'FEDEX_FREIGHT_ECONOMY'; // valid values STANDARD_OVERNIGHT, PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT, FEDEX_GROUND, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['PackagingType'] = 'YOUR_PACKAGING'; // valid values FEDEX_BOX, FEDEX_PAK, FEDEX_TUBE, YOUR_PACKAGING, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['Shipper'] = getProperty('shipper');
$request['RequestedShipment']['Recipient'] = addRecipient();
$request['RequestedShipment']['ShippingChargesPayment'] = addShippingChargesPayment();
$request['RequestedShipment']['FreightShipmentDetail'] = array(
    'FedExFreightAccountNumber' => getProperty('freightaccount'),
    'FedExFreightBillingContactAndAddress' => getProperty('freightbilling'),
    'PrintedReferences' => array(
        'Type' => 'SHIPPER_ID_NUMBER',
        'Value' => 'RBB1057'
    ),
    'Role' => 'SHIPPER',
    'PaymentType' => 'PREPAID',
    'CollectTermsType' => 'STANDARD',
    'DeclaredValuePerUnit' => array(
        'Currency' => 'USD',
        'Amount' => 50
    ),
    'LiabilityCoverageDetail' => array(
        'CoverageType' => 'NEW',
        'CoverageAmount' => array(
            'Currency' => 'USD',
            'Amount' => '50'
        )
    ),
    'TotalHandlingUnits' => 15,
    'ClientDiscountPercent' => 0,
    'PalletWeight' => array(
        'Units' => 'LB',
        'Value' => 20
    ),
    'ShipmentDimensions' => array(
        'Length' => 90,
        'Width' => 30,
        'Height' => 50,
        'Units' => 'IN'
    ),
    'LineItems' => array(
        'Id' => '111',
        'FreightClass' => 'CLASS_085',
        'ClassProvidedByCustomer' => false,
        'HandlingUnits' => 15,
        'Packaging' => 'PALLET',
        'BillOfLaddingNumber' => 'BOL_12345',
        'PurchaseOrderNumber' => 'PO_12345',
        'Description' => 'Heavy Stuff',
        'Weight' => array(
            'Value' => 50.0,
            'Units' => 'LB'
        ),
        'Dimensions' => array(
            'Length' => 90,
            'Width' => 30,
            'Height' => 50,
            'Units' => 'IN'
        ),
        'Volume' => array(
            'Units' => 'CUBIC_FT',
            'Value' => 30
        )
    )
);


$request['RequestedShipment']['RateRequestTypes'] = 'ACCOUNT';
$request['RequestedShipment']['RateRequestTypes'] = 'LIST';
$request['RequestedShipment']['PackageCount'] = '1';
$request['RequestedShipment']['CarrierCodes'] = 'FXFR';
$request['RequestedShipment']['RequestedPackageLineItems'] = addPackageLineItem1();


try {
    error_log('i am at try');
    if (setEndpoint('changeEndpoint')) {
        $newLocation = $client->__setLocation(setEndpoint('endpoint'));
        error_log('i am at changeEndpoint');
    }

    $response = $client->getRates($request);
    error_log('i am at response okay');
    if ($response->HighestSeverity != 'FAILURE' && $response->HighestSeverity != 'ERROR') {
        $rateReply = $response->RateReplyDetails;
        echo '<table border="1">';
        echo '<tr><th>Rate Details</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr>';
        trackDetails($rateReply, '');
        echo '</table>';

        printSuccess($client, $response);
    } else {
        printError($client, $response);
    }

    writeToLog($client);    // Write to log file   
} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    printFault($exception, $client);
}


function addRecipient()
{
    $recipient = array(
        'Contact' => array(
            'PersonName' => 'Sender Name',
            'CompanyName' => 'Sender Company Name',
            'PhoneNumber' => '1234567890'
        ),
        'Address' => array(
            'StreetLines' => array('12148 Jollyville Rd'),
            'City' => 'Austin',
            'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'TX',
            'PostalCode' => '78759',
            'CountryCode' => 'US'
        )
    );
    return $recipient;
}

function addShippingChargesPayment()
{
    $shippingChargesPayment = array(
        'PaymentType' => 'SENDER', // valid values RECIPIENT, SENDER and THIRD_PARTY
        'Payor' => array(
            'ResponsibleParty' => array(
                'AccountNumber' => getProperty('freightaccount'),
                'CountryCode' => 'US')
        )
    );
    return $shippingChargesPayment;
}

function addShipper()
{
    $shipper = array
    (
        'Contact' => array
        (
            'PersonName' => 'Rubaiet M',
            'CompanyName' => 'ELS',
            'PhoneNumber' => '019130191355'
        ),
        'Address' => array(
            'StreetLines' => array('1100 E Howard Ln'),
            'City' => 'Austin',
            'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'TX',
            'PostalCode' => '78753',
            'CountryCode' => 'US'
        )
    );
    return $shipper;
} // end of function addShipper

function addPackageLineItem1()
{
    error_log('i am in 152');

    $packageLineItem = array(
        'SequenceNumber' => 1,
        'GroupNumber'       => 1,
        'GroupPackageCount' => 1,
        'Weight' => array(
            'Value' => 450.0,
            'Units' => 'LB'
        ),
        'InsuredValue' => array(
            'Amount' => 695.0,
            'Currency' => "USD"
        ),
        'setGroupPackageCount' => 1
    );
    return $packageLineItem;
}


?>
```

The FedEx response is :

```
The transaction returned an Error.
Severity: ERROR
Source: crs
Code: 2101
Message: Package 1 - Physical packaging type is missing or invalid
LocalizedMessage: Package 1 - Physical packaging type is missing or invalid
Id: PACKAGE_INDEX
Value: 1
```

Comment: I've not done any LTL shipping, but based on the error message, does adding: `'PackagingType' => 'PLT'` as a separate key/value pair after `Packaging` help?

Comment: @PaulT. thanks for the reply. I am still trying to complete working LTL rate service. but still having problem with it

Comment: Still getting the same error adding the packaging type?

Comment: Yes it is. Same error. I am trying to find working fine LTL example PHP code or XML file.

Comment: Along with my previous suggestion, can you try changing: `'Packaging' => 'PALLET'` to `'Packaging' => 'YOUR_PACKAGING'`?  I'll see if I can dig up an LTL example some where.

Comment: Never mind about the `YOUR_PACKAGING` suggestion, the `PALLET` that you have set appears to be ok. I did find [this info](https://developertest.fedex.com/api/en-gp/catalog/ltl-freight/v1/docs.html#operation/Create%20Freight%20Pickup) ... if it could be helpful?

Comment: @PaulT. I already added $request['RequestedShipment']['PackagingType'] = 'PALLET'; but still same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using RateService_v31.wsdl and still having problem. But when I swap to RateService_v16.wsdl BOOOM my code is working fine.

Here is the my LTL Freight request code. I hope someone having same problem and it can solve the issue.

```
<?php
// Copyright 2009, FedEx Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Version 12.0.0

require_once('../../fedex-common.php5');

$newline = "<br />";
//The WSDL is not included with the sample code.
//Please include and reference in $path_to_wsdl variable.
$path_to_wsdl = "../wsdl/RateService_v16.wsdl";

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "1");

$client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl, array('trace' => 1)); // Refer to http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.soap.php for more information

$request['WebAuthenticationDetail'] = array(
    'ParentCredential' => array(
        'Key' => getProperty('parentkey'),
        'Password' => getProperty('parentpassword')
    ),
    'UserCredential' => array(
        'Key' => getProperty('key'),
        'Password' => getProperty('password')
    )
);
$request['ClientDetail'] = array(
    'AccountNumber' => getProperty('shipaccount'),
    'MeterNumber' => getProperty('meter')
);
$request['TransactionDetail'] = array('CustomerTransactionId' => ' *** Rate Request using PHP ***');
$request['Version'] = array(
    'ServiceId' => 'crs',
    'Major' => '16',
    'Intermediate' => '0',
    'Minor' => '0'
);
$request['ReturnTransitAndCommit'] = true;
$request['RequestedShipment']['DropoffType'] = 'REGULAR_PICKUP'; // valid values REGULAR_PICKUP, REQUEST_COURIER, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['ShipTimestamp'] = date('c');
$request['RequestedShipment']['ServiceType'] = 'FEDEX_FREIGHT_ECONOMY'; // valid values STANDARD_OVERNIGHT, PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT, FEDEX_GROUND, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['PackagingType'] = 'YOUR_PACKAGING'; // valid values FEDEX_BOX, FEDEX_PAK, FEDEX_TUBE, YOUR_PACKAGING, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['Shipper'] = getProperty('shipper');
$request['RequestedShipment']['Recipient'] = addRecipient();
$request['RequestedShipment']['ShippingChargesPayment'] = addShippingChargesPayment();
$request['RequestedShipment']['FreightShipmentDetail'] = array(
    'FedExFreightAccountNumber' => getProperty('freightaccount'),
    'FedExFreightBillingContactAndAddress' => getProperty('freightbilling'),
    'PrintedReferences' => array(
        'Type' => 'SHIPPER_ID_NUMBER',
        'Value' => 'RBB1057'
    ),
    'Role' => 'SHIPPER',
    'PaymentType' => 'PREPAID',
    'CollectTermsType' => 'STANDARD',
    'DeclaredValuePerUnit' => array(
        'Currency' => 'USD',
        'Amount' => 50
    ),
    'LiabilityCoverageDetail' => array(
        'CoverageType' => 'NEW',
        'CoverageAmount' => array(
            'Currency' => 'USD',
            'Amount' => '50'
        )
    ),
    'TotalHandlingUnits' => 1,
    'ClientDiscountPercent' => 0,
    'PalletWeight' => array(
        'Units' => 'LB',
        'Value' => 20
    ),
    'ShipmentDimensions' => array(
        'Length' => 90,
        'Width' => 30,
        'Height' => 50,
        'Units' => 'IN'
    ),
    'LineItems' => array(
        'FreightClass' => 'CLASS_085',
        'Packaging' => 'SKID',
        'Weight' => array(
            'Value' => 50.0,
            'Units' => 'LB'
        )
    )
);


$request['RequestedShipment']['RateRequestTypes'] = 'NONE';
$request['RequestedShipment']['PackageCount'] = '1';
$request['RequestedShipment']['CarrierCodes'] = 'FXFR';
$request['RequestedShipment']['RequestedPackageLineItems'] = addPackageLineItem1();


try {
    error_log('i am at try');
    if (setEndpoint('changeEndpoint')) {
        $newLocation = $client->__setLocation(setEndpoint('endpoint'));
        error_log('i am at changeEndpoint');
    }

    $response = $client->getRates($request);
    error_log('i am at response okay');
    if ($response->HighestSeverity != 'FAILURE' && $response->HighestSeverity != 'ERROR') {
        $rateReply = $response->RateReplyDetails;
        echo '<table border="1">';
        echo '<tr><th>Rate Details</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr>';
        trackDetails($rateReply, '');
        echo '</table>';

        printSuccess($client, $response);
    } else {
        printError($client, $response);
    }

    writeToLog($client);    // Write to log file   
} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    printFault($exception, $client);
}


function addRecipient()
{
    $recipient = array(
        'Contact' => array(
            'PersonName' => 'Sender Name',
            'CompanyName' => 'Sender Company Name',
            'PhoneNumber' => '1234567890'
        ),
        'Address' => array(
            'StreetLines' => array('12148 Jollyville Rd'),
            'City' => 'Austin',
            'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'TX',
            'PostalCode' => '78759',
            'CountryCode' => 'US'
        )
    );
    return $recipient;
}

function addShippingChargesPayment()
{
    $shippingChargesPayment = array(
        'PaymentType' => 'SENDER', // valid values RECIPIENT, SENDER and THIRD_PARTY
        'Payor' => array(
            'ResponsibleParty' => array(
                'AccountNumber' => getProperty('freightaccount'),
                'CountryCode' => 'US')
        )
    );
    return $shippingChargesPayment;
}

function addShipper()
{
    $shipper = array
    (
        'Contact' => array
        (
            'PersonName' => 'Rubaiet M',
            'CompanyName' => 'ELS',
            'PhoneNumber' => '019130191355'
        ),
        'Address' => array(
            'StreetLines' => array('12148 Jollyville Rd'),
            'City' => 'Austin',
            'StateOrProvinceCode' => 'TX',
            'PostalCode' => '78759',
            'CountryCode' => 'US'
        )
    );
    return $shipper;
} // end of function addShipper

function addPackageLineItem1()
{
    $packageLineItem = array(
        'SequenceNumber' => 1,
        'GroupNumber'       => 1,
        'GroupPackageCount' => 1,
        'Weight' => array(
            'Value' => 55.0,
            'Units' => 'LB'
        ),
        'InsuredValue' => array(
            'Amount' => 695.0,
            'Currency' => "USD"
        ),
        'setGroupPackageCount' => 1
    );
    return $packageLineItem;
}


?>
```